# Hover to Pause Autoplay in Magnific Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I've created a Magnific Popup that displays a gallery of html slides.  By using

```
callbacks: {
open: setInterval(function() {
         $.magnificPopup.instance.next()
            }, 8000)},
```

I have been able to make the slideshow auto play.  However, I cannot find a hover pause (or any other pause) that seems to work.  Can anyone help me with this?